# Specifying column names with unstack

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a really wide database in Excel that I'm trying to unstack into a DF.

The data looks like this:

```
Date_1      Date_2     Date_3...   ...Date_n
A1          B1         C1           N1
A2          B2         C2           N2
A3          B3         C3           N3
A4          B4         C4           N4
```

The output I'm shooting for adds some column names and is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     Dates      Data
  0  Date_1     A1
  1             A2
  2             A3
  3             A4
  4  Date_2     B1
  ...  ....       ...
  N  Date_N     N1 etc
```

My idea here is that I can then concatenate these two columns and use them as unique identifiers to merge this dataframe with others

I've tried two different variants of unstack here but neither have been successful. 
The first pass looks like this

```
df = pd.read_Excel('DataFile.xls', sheet_name = 'Data').unstack()
```

The output here is

```
Date_1    0    A1
          1    A2
          ...  ...
Date_N    N    N1 etc
```

So it's close to what I'm looking for except (a) my data doesn't have any columns headers; and (b) I have what looks like a series of (0,1,...N) in the middle of the outputs. I thought this might be the index but I'm not sure why it would be placed here.

More in hope than expectation, I then tried naming the columns via

```
df = pd.read_Excel('DataFile.xls', sheet_name = 'Data', names = ['Dates', 'Data').unstack()
```

I wasn't surprised when it didn't work...I got the error message:

ValueError: Number of passed names did not match number of header fields in the file

So now I am stuck and would enormously appreciate some wisdom!

Thank you in advance

Comment: using melt works fine: `df.melt(var_name='Dates',value_name='Data')`

Comment: I'm sorry @ anky_91...that's not working for me.  When I specify the names in pd.read_Excel what is returned is a message "Number of passed names did not match number of header fields in the file"

Comment: ...and now it does. Sorry - I've got no idea why it didn't work properly at first. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.